# ARIMA identification process

Tags: time-series

I have a 2000 SKUs, I want to identify the ARIMA process for them, what is the best way to do that?, which tools should I use?

thank you very much.
Roji

Answer (score 2):

:Roji When identifying an ARIMA model you must be careful to incorporate any needed deterministic structure such as Pulses, Level Shifts , Seasonal Pulses and/or Local Time Trends. You might try googling sites that offer Automatic ARIMA modelling or simply Automatic ARIMA and then arrange for a trial version. Some advanced packages actually provide step-by-step details as to how the appropriate ARIMA model gets formed. In my opinion stay clear of 'Black Boxes" which shield you from a better understanding of the modelling process. You might also inquire about discounts for universities!

Comment: There is an arima.auto function in R's "forecast" package, but I agree with the above comment that black box algorithms are never desirable

Comment: The R forecast package is rather limited as it assumes no Pulses, Level Shifts, Seasonal Pulses and/or Local Time Trends which yields very poor results. The impact of not dealing with these four kinds of interventions is dramatic.